# HEVC: Remove packets from bit stream video

Tags: video, video-streaming, video-processing, hevc, h.265

Is there a way to remove some predefined packets from the bit stream video resulted from the HEVC encoder (HM 14.0) in order to decode the new bit stream video and see if I have distortions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You might have got this by now.
But still, it might help some newbie in hevc.

Of course, you can do this!
For instance just append same encoded bitstream to itself.

```
cp bitstream.hevc temp.hevc
cat temp.hevc >>bitstream.hevc
rm temp.hevc
```

And decode the resulting bitstream. You will find the video repeated.

You just shouldn't mess with the sps, pps or vps parameters.

Also you can play around with bitstream by opening it in beyond compare in hex mode, change the old values.